# A Problem with A Relative Clause

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In the film, "Dr. Zhivago" (1965), narrator, general Yevgraf Zhivago said:

> "Finally, they (the Russian soldiers) did what all the armies dreamed of doing."

(They mutinied and began the long walk home.)

In Latin, this incorporates a relative clause:

> "postremo, fecerunt quid omnes exercitus somniabant." =

> "Finally, they did what all the armies were dreaming of."

Is this correct?

EDIT 18/2/2022

(Thanks to Kingshorsey):

> "postremo, fecerunt quod omnes exercitus somniaverunt."

Comment: Where's the indirect speech? "They did what [= that which] everybody dreamt of" is a simple relative clause, no?

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Well-spotted. How did I miss that?

Comment: @tony two comments: primum, for a relative clause, change "quid" to "quod." secundum, I think either present or perfect tense makes more sense for a general statement.